# Enabling and disabling a fine uploader

Tags: knockout.js, fine-uploader

I am using fine-uploader and knock out as well. I would like to enable the fine upload only when a user clicks a certain button. On page load, I would like to disable the fine uploader and enable only when a certain button is clicked.

My attpempt:

```
<input type="text" class="input-medium"  data-bind="value: someThing"/>
                            <div class="fileupload fileupload-new pull-right" data-bind="enable:$root.isClicked,uploader: true">
```

isClicked is an observable which is initially false. Hence, fineuploader should be disabled, but its not.

Comment: What, specifically, are you trying to disable?  The file input button?  The drop zone?  Both?  Something else?

Comment: The file input field and the file input button.

Comment: I am still confused.  The file input field and the button are the same element.  Why dont you simply hold off initializing the uploader until the user presses whatever button you are referring to?

Comment: Well, ther are two button, new and cancel. When new is pressed, the uploader should be enabled, when cancel is pressed, it should be disabled. Initializing it will not work in this scenario

Comment: Can't you just hide/show the container that holds the uploader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my last comment, simply show or hide the container that holds the uploader when appropriate.  If you need to reset the upload to its original state, use the [`reset` API method](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#reset).